# how to remove the indexPath.row which i like to delete to the UserDefraults by a set function

Tags: swift, uitableview

Im delete a row and would like to delete it also in the data Manager how do i pass which row to delete in the indexpath?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete{

        self.tableView.beginUpdates()

        print("Deleted was pressed")

        records.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

      //  DataManager.getInstance().setNewRecord(array: [UserRecordDataManager])
  //      DataManager.getInstance().setNewRecord(array: UserRecordDataManager)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
        tableView.reloadData()
        print(records.count)

    }
}

/// Data Manager- doing the SET option

    public func setNewRecord(array: [UserRecordDataManager] ){

            records.remove=???
            self.records = getRecords()
        print(DataManager.getInstance().records.count)

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
in the data manager:

   public func removeRecord(index: Int){
            if getRecords().isEmpty{
                print("ERROR - there is no recoreds")
                return
            }else{
                self.records = getRecords()
                self.records.remove(at: index)

                let encodeData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.records)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encodeData, forKey: "records")
            }
        }




in the tableview:

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete{

            self.tableView.beginUpdates()

            print("Deleted was pressed")

            let index = indexPath.row

            records.remove(at: index)

            print(index)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            DataManager.getInstance().removeRecord(index: index)

            self.tableView.endUpdates()
            tableView.reloadData()
            print(records.count)

    }
```